# Is SMB 1.0 Client vulnerable to the port 139 hack or is it just the server?

Tags: windows-10, networking, security, nas, smb

I have an old Buffalo NAS that only supports SMB 1.0.  The recent forced upgrade to Windows 10 turned off SMB 1.0 support by default. So, now the Windows box can’t access the shares on the server.

I found I can turn on the SMB 1.0 support in the Windows Features (as revealed elsewhere) to make it work.

I turned on SMB 1.0 Client to enable access to the NAS.

#### My question is SMB 1.0 Client vulnerable to the port 139 hack or is it just the server.

It seems the NAS is vulnerable and I can’t fix that (yet?).

Comment: Any workstation or server with SMBv1 enabled is vulnerable to unauthorized access.

Comment: Exactly which "port 139 hack" are you referring to?

Comment: SMB1 is not as secure as the latest versions of the SMB protocol. You should remove older devices that still rely on SMB1.

Answer (score 0):

> My question is SMB 1.0 Client vulnerable to the port 139 hack or is it just the server.

WannaCry which is the most well know malware associated with the EternalBlue vulnerability was a worm.  WannaCry would infect every vulnerable device on the network.

Once WannaCry infected a machine it would encrypt every single volume accessible by the user.  This means the volume directly connected to the machine and any volumes accessible over a network.

Unlike ransomeware before it, WannaCry encrypted every accessible drive, and the criminals beyond WannaCry were competent and didn’t leak the key.

> The recent forced upgrade to Windows 10 turned off SMB 1.0 support by default. So, now the Windows box can’t access the shares on the server. I found I can turn on the SMB 1.0 support in the Windows Features (as revealed elsewhere) to make it work. I turned on SMB 1.0 Client to enable access to the NAS.

The upgrade to Windows 10 wasn’t forced.  However, SMBv1 on Windows 10 has been patch against EternalBlue, but SMBv1 isn’t considered secure and you should absolutely upgrade your equipment.

Comment: @jj_ - Microsoft patched EternalBlue but there might be other vulnerabilities that exist with SMBv1 that don’t exist with SMBv3.  Do you really want to take the risk?  SMBv1 was retired long before EternalBlue was known.

Comment: there might be other vulnerabilities for newer versions of SMB too... I understand that newer versions are stronger by design, but once v1 has been hardened then why it is vulnerable to new unknown attacks, more than newer versions could be? Do you have any sources clearly stating how *patched* SMBv1 is still fundamentally broken compared to v2+? Because I couldn't find any...

Comment: Difference between SMBv1 and SMBv3 is that Microsoft will patch SMBv3, SMBv3 contains designs decisions, that SMBv1 does support

Comment: did you mean `does *not* support` in place of `does support`?

Comment: @jj_ - Yes, I indeed do mean that